# nodejs - Export queries result to other files

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm doing some query to retrieve some data from a database, and trying to export said data to be used in my nodejs aplication. But everything I've tried so far, does not work.

```
r.js

async function site() {
  var test = await db
    .select("*")
    .from("site_credentials")
    .then(data => {
      return data;
    });

  return test;
}

module.exports = { user: site().then(data=>{return data})}
```

but I always get Promise pending. Even when I do the imports:

```
import users = require("./r")

users.then(data=>{return data})
```

and still doesnt work. How can I fix this?

Thank you,

Comment: Yes; you can't cheat async.

Comment: @SLaks what would be a workaround for this? My work wants the to get the data from the database, I can't save the credentials locally.

Comment: You need to make everything async.

Comment: Thank you! @SLaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, there's no reason to resolve a promise and immediately return the same object resolved in its then block.  Just omit the "then" if there is nothing else you need to do.

So this:

```
async function site() {
  var test = await db
    .select("*")
    .from("site_credentials")
    .then(data => {
      return data;  <--- this isn't necessary.  Only adds noise unless there is something else you need to do.  It's similar to "catching" and immediately "rethrowing" an error... just pointless
    });

  return test;
}
```

Can be this:

```
async function site() {
  var test = await db
    .select("*")
    .from("site_credentials");    
  return test;
}
```

Secondly, I'm not really sure why you're trying to resolve it in the export.  Just export the function.

```
module.exports = site;
```

Then when you require it elsewhere in your app, call it and resolve it there:

```
const users = require("./r")

users.then(data=>{
  // do something with your data here...
})
```

Note that in your first example, you are exporting an object, containing a "users" property which is the function.  If you do it that way, you would need to invoke it like so:

```
const users = require("./r")

users.users().then(data=>{
  // do something with your data here...
})
```

You can see that `users.users` clearly doesn't make sense.  So, export properly to avoid that.  Export only the function itself, not nested inside some other object.

But, if you look closely, you'll notice another thing I did wrong.  I'm exporting a "site" function, yet requiring it in as a "users" function.  Naming conventions matter.  If this function is called "site" here, you ought to require (or import depending on your module loader...) it in as "site"... thus:

```
const site = require('./r');
```

Otherwise you just confuse the crud out of a fellow developer.